# Exception EOSError in module rtl220 bpl at 00050A4D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, appmethod

I have embarcadero radstudio xe8 on a windows 10 machine. Everything was working  perfectly till about 2weeks ago. Everytime I try to start Delphi xe8 I get an error :"Exception EOSError in module rtl220.bpl at 00050A4D.System Error.  Code 111.  The  file name is too long. " I tried reinstalling a couple of times and I even tried installing appmethod but I still get the same error.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you consulted Embarcadero about this error?

Comment: If I had to guess, the IDE's files got installed in the *virtualized* `Program Files(x86)` portion of the user profile's VirtualStore instead of in the *true* `Program Files(x86)` folder. VirtualStore paths can easily get very long. For example: files installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\16.0\...` might be physically located at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\16.0\...` instead. Like SebastianZ said, use Process Monitor to find out what real paths are being accessed and if any one is failing with a "too long" error.

Comment: Although, technically speaking, `The file name is too long` is a little misleading, because error 111 is `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`, which is reported by all kinds of different APIs that are not related to file names at all, so it is not actually guaranteed that a long filename is what is causing the IDE to fail with error 111.  Maybe the IDE is simply passing a short buffer to an API that is expecting a larger buffer and the IDE is not compensating for the error.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue today. I've traced it to a [GetAdaptersInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call, and it turned out that for some reason (VirtualBox is my main suspect) I've had over 50 network adapters registered on my system. Removing all of them fixed the issue.

Comment: Had the same problem right now with 16 network adapters and disabling(!), not deleting, one of them made the IDE start again already. Reported this issue to Embarcadero as well: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-28112

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info in your question in order to tell what exactly is wrong. Try using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) in order to check what files Delphi is trying to access. It will also show the errors of these file operations.

Answer (score 0):

as they uri2x tell you the problem is that RAD Studio having issue with many network adapters registered more than 20 will not work properly you will have problem with debbuging and run project and you may find many cmd.exe process running in your system 
delete duplicate and non needed network adapters registered on  "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"

that will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help. I had a similar problem, error code 5 Access is denied. This turned out to related to a thread started to test an internet connection on an embedded panel (using BeginThread). If the user exits the form (which is testing the internet connection) immediately after displaying the form, the AV occurs.

On my development PC, the internet connection test was successful...and so fast I never saw the problem! After struggling for several hours, I finally tracked it down to this thread and reproduced it by disconnecting my network cable.

The solution was straightforward: When exiting the form (eg. in the FormDestroy event) ensure the thread is definitely not running before continuing.